# JNDI lookup different between a war and an ear

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, jndi, ear

I have the following code:

```
JndiDataSourceLookup lookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
DataSource ds= lookup.getDataSource( name );
```

This code works when deployed in a war, but fails we deployed inside an ear (actually a war inside an ear).

The exception is:

```
Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:comp/env/jdbc/myDS'; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up comp/env/jdbc/myDS in /app/webapp/testapp/855064630.; remaining name 'comp/env/jdbc/myDS'
```

We are not declaring resource-refs in the web.xml

We're using the Spring JDBC utils, and deploying inside weblogic 12c.  What are the differences between doing this in an ear or a war?

**UPDATE**

Adding the resource refs to the war (both in web.xml and the weblogic.xml file) made it work.  The refs map the exact same jndi name: jdbc/myDS -> jdbc/myDS.

Comment: In weblogic you can login to the admin console, go to the server your ear is deployed on, and click View JNDI Tree. My guess is your war didn't deploy correctly and you won't find your data source in the JNDI tree. Otherwise the lookup is the exact same.

Comment: I checked the JNDI tree and the data source is there. I forgot to mention, but the data source is deployed in weblogic, not through the ear file.